# How to test API using Hurl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

i want to test API from my backend engineer, while he using Rails. He only documented this:

```
POST /api/v1/sessions
Params Pattern :
{ session: { email: "apple@apple.com", password: “apple”,
} }
```

How i test this using Hurl/Postman?
I already tried several times and the error is

```
{
"status": "400",
"error": "Bad Request"
}
```

FYI : i put application/json as Header for Accept and Content-Type. And the

```
{ session: { email: "apple@apple.com", password: “apple”,
} }
```

as paramater body.

Thanks...welcome to use any apps/online via browser.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used HURL till now but i use [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) extension for Chrome.